# getting alerts for new version of application

Tags: android

I m working on one application and it is ready to be launch on android market.
suppose user has installed the application from android market. and after 3 months if i launch i new version of my app how the user will be notify that new version is available?

Queries:

1. Do i need to make changes in my current app??
2. Or it will be done automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need any changes in new version.
2. Yes, all users reseive notification that new version uploaded in market. Just upload new apk in first version post. Reseive came veri fast but need some time to refresh in web site market!